# html2canvas is working in IE, not working in google chrome

Tags: css, angularjs, google-chrome, html2canvas

I'm trying to export the html  part as a pdf file using html2canvas and jsPDF libraries. However, this functionality is working fine in IE and the contents that are available in the window scope is available in the exported pdf where the content inside the scroll bar is not available in chrome. The  part has multiple rows where each row is iterated using angularjs ng-repeat and each row has customized css part. Each row should be exported with the applied css and the dynamic data that is available in the screen. Posting the codefor your reference,
[Chrome Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdA3X.jpg)

[IE Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhN0B.jpg)

Script Code:

```
$scope.exportFunctionViewData = function(){
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('functionViewExport') , {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var content = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                var imgWidth = 210; 
                var pageHeight = 295;  
                var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
                var heightLeft = imgHeight;

                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                var position = 0;

                doc.addImage(content, 'JPEG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                heightLeft -= pageHeight;

                while (heightLeft >= 0) {
                  position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
                  doc.addPage();
                  doc.addImage(content, 'JPEG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                  heightLeft -= pageHeight;
                }
                doc.save($scope.title + '-FunctionView.pdf');    
            }
        });
    };
```